# Last row is being copied multiple times when VBA is run

Tags: excel, vba

When I run the below VBA code, instead of copying the rows with column value "Onboarding Begun by SAM" it copies the last row with the value "Onboarding Begun by SAM" multiple times.

Example: Data in Universe Sheet

| Column A | ... | Column M |
| --- | --- | --- |
| ABC | ... | Onboarding Begun by SAM |
| ABD | ... | No value |
| ABE | ... | Onboarding Begun by SAM |

Output required in "Onboarding Begun by SAM" sheet:

|  |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- |
| ABC | ... | Onboarding Begun by SAM |
| ABE | ... | Onboarding Begun by SAM |

Instead, it's copying indefinitely and crashing:

|  |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- |
| ABE | ... | Onboarding Begun by SAM |
| ABE | ... | Onboarding Begun by SAM |
| ABE | ... | Onboarding Begun by SAM |

Can you please help me fix this.

```vb
Sub CopyDataBasedOnStatusCondtion()
    Dim lRow, cRow As Long
    Dim xlRange As Range
    
    lRow = Sheets("Universe").Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row 'Last row in your main sheet
    
    iLastRow = Sheets("Onboarding Begun by SAM").Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row
    Set xlRange = Sheets("Onboarding Begun by SAM").Range("A2:B" & iLastRow)
    
    'Let's find these items in the Main sheet and send to the respective sheet
    For j = lRow To 1 Step -1        
        'looping throu your main sheet and copying the data into respective sheet
        If Sheets("Universe").Range("M" & j) = "Onboarding Begun by SAM" Then
            valueToFind = Sheets("Universe").Range("A" & j)
            For Each xlCell In xlRange
                If xlCell.Value <> valueToFind Then
                    cRow = Sheets("Onboarding Begun by SAM").Range("A50000").End(xlUp).Row
                    Sheets("Universe").Rows(j).Copy Destination:=Sheets("Onboarding Begun by SAM").Range("A" & cRow + 1)
                End If
            Next
        End If
    Next
    
    Sheets("Onboarding Begun by SAM").Range("A1:R50000").RemoveDuplicates Columns:=1, Header:=xlYes
End Sub
```

Comment: `If xlCell.Value <> valueToFind Then` you mean to copy *non-matching* rows?  It would help to expalin exactly what this part of your code is meant to check for.

Comment: Do you mean to copy the row only if the value in ColA doesn't already exist in ColA/B on sheet "Onboarding Begun by SAM" ?

Comment: maybe a fill equation would be better?

Answer (score 1):

just change the xldown to xlup in your ilastrow

```
    Sub CopyDataBasedOnStatusCondtion()
    Dim lRow, cRow As Long
    Dim xlRange As Range
    
    lRow = Sheets("Universe").Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row 'Last row in your main sheet
    
    iLastRow = Sheets("Onboarding Begun by SAM").Range("A1").End(xlUp).Row
    Set xlRange = Sheets("Onboarding Begun by SAM").Range("A2:B" & iLastRow)
    
    'Let's find these items in the Main sheet and send to the respective sheet
    For j = lRow To 1 Step -1
        'looping throu your main sheet and copying the data into respective sheet
        If Sheets("Universe").Range("M" & j) = "Onboarding Begun by SAM" Then
            valueToFind = Sheets("Universe").Range("A" & j)
            For Each xlCell In xlRange
                If xlCell.Value <> valueToFind Then
                    cRow = Sheets("Onboarding Begun by SAM").Range("A50000").End(xlUp).Row
                    Sheets("Universe").Rows(j).Copy Destination:=Sheets("Onboarding Begun by SAM").Range("A" & cRow + 1)
                End If
            Next
        End If
    Next
    
    Sheets("Onboarding Begun by SAM").Range("A1:R50000").RemoveDuplicates Columns:=1, Header:=xlYes
End Sub
```